# What does "Cannot set color of undefined" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used the following function to change my "clock website" to a lighter theme.

```
var light = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('themechange').style.color = "black"
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.backgroundColor = "white";
};
```

I get the error in the title when I try to run the function.  If you need more code, inspect element [here](https://caa8edf10c487b5ff2dc93e7192b6b4ab1ae15da-www.googledrive.com/host/0B-Yxt1Eo-wZVa05aNzM2alk3Rnc)

Comment: Why are you setting the colors with JavaScript? Just add and remove a class and let CSS styles do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [`Document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) return [`NodeLists`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) objects.

You cannot apply settings directly to a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you have to iterate through it and apply the settings to each [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node).

However for you can use [`Document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) to reference the `body` element directly.

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is [not supported in Internet Explorer 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname) but [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall).

```js
/*    Select all elements with the class `themechange`
 *    Iterate with a for loop
 *    Set each element's background color to `black`
 *    Set the body's background color to `white`
 */
var light = function() {
    var themeChanges = document.querySelectorAll('.themechange'), themeChange, i;
    for(i = 0; (themeChange = themeChanges[i]); i++) {
        themeChange.style.color = "black"
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
};
```

Comment: what's the end condition?

Comment: (themeChange= themeChanges[i]) but not if i < themeChanges.length or something in the for loop, jw

Comment: oh it won't give an indexOutOfBounds? for themeChanges?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79723/discussion-between-daemedeor-and-humble-rumble).

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName function returns a NodeList, not an element. You'll need to use a loop to change the style property of all of the elements in the list instead of trying to access the non-existent style property of the NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over the returned object stopping at `i` == `Object.length` and access each element at index `i`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('themechange')[0].style.color = "black"
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
```